# How to snap to road using lat long as parameters

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Snaptoroad Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap)

The problem i am having is simple but to me is really difficult as i am 
a newbie student just started learning Javascript and i would like to 
start my first project using simple Google Map API to snap a set of coordinates
(approx 100~200 points) to roads.

In the code provided in the Google API page, it shows a map with tool bar,line drawer and a map. After we drew the line,the map automatically snap that line to the road.

So now, all i wanted is not drawing the line,but inputing lat and long to generate corresponding snapped road. What do i need to delete in the code and what parameters ,how to input the parameters to Google?

all i have done is created a file reader which read text file stored in local drive.

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

var file = this.files[0];

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(progressEvent){

var lines = this.result.split('\n');
for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
  //alert(lines[line]);
  var split = [];
  split = lines[line].split(',');
  window.xcoord.push(split[0]);
  window.ycoord.push(split[1]);}
}
reader.readAsText(file); };
```

After loading the coordinates into xcoord and ycoord array,i would like to create a button that after onclicked, it generates the map and the snapped line.
Probably something similar to:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function runSnapToRoad(path) {
var pathValues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
pathValues.push(path.getAt(i).toUrlValue()); }

$.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
interpolate: true,
key: apiKey,
path: pathValues.join('|')
}, function(data) {
processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
drawSnappedPolyline();
getAndDrawSpeedLimits();});}
```

What parameters needed to input as 'path' in the function runSnapToRoad, Also,
what are the useless code that can be erased in the example? Please help me and i know i have much to learn. ( I have been struggling for few days as there isn't any similar problems/example can be found ), Thank you
very much!!

Comment: Are your `pathValues` items already comma-separated lat-lng values before being joined with "|"? For example, `path=60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by concatenating string using a while loop with php.

```
<?php
$stringJoin = "";
$index = 0;
$handle = fopen($_GET['fileName'], "r");
if ($handle) {
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
      $index++;
      if ($index == 99) {
        break;
      }
      $stringJoin .= trim($line)."|";
  }
  fclose($handle); }
  echo $index;
  echo "<br>";
  $stringJoin = substr($stringJoin, 0, -1);
  echo $stringJoin;?>
```

and inputing it like this:

```
path: <?php echo '"'.$stringJoin.'"';?>
```

and the graph is plotted perfectly.